# icorrect image url after select from elfinder in tinymce

Tags: yii2, tinymce, elfinder

I have problem with url of selected image in tinymce . elfinder work correctly It's upload image in the correct folder and show in elfinder , after I am choosing picture and show the url in modal like this:
[image]

the url is like this: ../../uploads/tinymce/2.jpg
when I am in module my structure is like this: app/admin/
two dot came back to correct url and show picture in admin module but when I want to show picture with text in front end the url is not correct how can I fix this?

the plugins I used: 2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget, alexantr\elfinder

Comment: you mean when you save the picture you are unable to show that picture along with the content where ever you want it to be displayed ?

Comment: yes, exactly  how can I correct it?

Comment: I don't know well about yii2-elfinder. But I have a hint to fix it maybe, that's recently version of the elFinder can use `elFinderInstance.convAbsUrl(url)`. Please see https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-4.x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , in tinymce for this problem you have to declare 
convert_urls to false , it's default is set to true aftar that the url is true